# Most efficient way to get first digit of a double/float

Tags: multilingual

For example if I have a `float`/`double` variable:

```
float f = 1212512.028423;
double d = 938062.3453;
int f1 = 1; 
int d1 = 9;
```

What's the fastest way to get the first digit of those number?

```
int first_digit(double n) {
  while(n>10) n/=10;
  return n;
}
```

Is this the most efficient?

I need an implementation that doesn't involves `char`/`string`, that would be also works (or give the best performance in their specific language). The language are `Ruby`, `Python`, `C#`, `Java`, `C++`, `Go`, `JavaScript`, `PHP`.

Comment: You could extract the exponent and divide it by log2(10). This should give you an exponent for scaling within +-1 of the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Try this.
double d = 938062.3453;
int f1 = Int32.Parse(d.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: It's a bit slow, but if the performance is not your concern, defiantly it’s a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Both mentioned solutions will crash at number -0.0123. I have constructed a different method for slightly different purpose:

```
public static double InteligentRound(double X, int kam=0)
{           int zn = (X < 0) ? (-1) : (1);  //signum of the input
            X *= zn;  //we work with positive values only
            double exp = Math.Log10(X);  //exponent of 10
            exp = Math.Floor(exp);  
            double B = Math.Pow(10, exp);//the pure power of 10
            double FD = X / B;  //lies between 1 and 10
            if (kam == 0) FD = Math.Round(FD);
            if (kam < 0) FD = Math.Floor(FD);  //Now, FD is the first digit
            if (kam > 0) FD = Math.Ceiling(FD);
            return (zn * FD * B);
        }
```